# View pdfs stored in assets folder from listview click in fragment

Tags: android, listview, pdf, android-fragments

I have created a `ListView` in which I would like each item to open a certain .pdf file located in `assets/PDFS` folder located within my Android App. The following code does not throw any errors, but does not open the file either. Can someone share an idea for the solution?

Note that I am using Fragment

```
public class FreshFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    ListView lv;
    String[] titles;

    public FreshFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fresh, container, false);


        lv = (ListView)V.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return V;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            File pdfFile = new File("res/assets/peedee.pdf");
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a file in your assets in another app.  You need to write it to disk somewhere both apps can read it first, such as external storage.

Comment: only one app will be accessing the pdf files... the one that the pdfs are stored in

Comment: Then you're using the wrong type of intent.  Don't do an action view intent, that will look for any app that declares it can read pdfs.  Create an intent for the specific activity you want to run, and pass the filename as an intent extra.